# How to show iTerm2 completion suggestions in a menu while typing

Tags: terminal, autocomplete

In a presentation at Docker Con 2022, Shy Ruparel showed his iTerm2 terminal with an awesome completion/suggestion function. It shows command suggestions in a menu while typing, without pressing TAB key. It is also able to capture and show new possibilities dynamically, for example, the newly pulled 'fedora' image was shown as a new suggestion for 'docker run' command.

I did some researches on the Internet but couldn't find anything similar. Does anyone know what completion/suggestion software was use?

Screenshot:
[image: zsh-completion-screenshot]

You can see it in action here: https://docker.events.cube365.net/dockercon/2022/content/Videos/ba325a70-52da-4d54-a382-82cb6b7b718d, at 00:28:31.

Comment: `zsh` is not a terminal, it's a shell, but it can or can be configured to tell a terminal to display its completions in various forms. That particular form is not something that comes builtin in `zsh` AFAIK, and it seems it needs some ability that is specific to one terminal emulator in particular as I've never seen a terminal that lets applications render menus like that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the different b/w a shell and a terminal. After looking at the screenshot again, I could see that it's iTerm2. Probably the completion is a plugin for iTerm2, I'm doing other researches in that direction.

P/s: I updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I finally find out what was used, it is [Fig](https://fig.io), which adds "IDE-style autocomplete to your existing terminal". I've just downloaded it, now giving it a try for real experience.

You can download the tool from its home page or using `brew`:

```
brew install --cask fig
```